# simple If-Statemenet - batch script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I am new to Batch scripting and I have to apply a simple if statement. 
Certainly, the user gives the name of the script (c5) and one parameter. If the first parameter is "John" prints "Welcome John" else prints "Who are you?".

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
set msg1 = Welcome John
set msg2 = Who are you%?
if %1 == "John" echo %msg1% 
if not %1 == "John" echo %msg2%
pause
```

When I type "c5 " without parameters, shows: " "echo" cannot be processed syntactically at this point." (original: "echo" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden."
If I use any parament (c5 Johny either c5 kostas)  ECHO is turned off.

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces and quotes are funny things in dos batch, I got this to work.

```
@echo off
set msg1=Welcome John
set msg2=Who are you?
if %1 == John echo %msg1%
if not %1 == John echo %msg2%
pause
```

Comment: Everything works fine now, spaces and quotes were causing the problem. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This shows a way to use `/i` test for `John` or `john` or `joHN` etc without regard for case, and also shows another way to arrange the echoing.

This will also accept `two words` in `%1` and will not fail if `%1` is empty.

```
@echo off
set msg1=Welcome John
set msg2=Who are you?
if /i "%~1"=="John" (echo %msg1%) else (echo %msg2%)
pause
```